# Error 1931. The Windows Installer service cannot update the system file C:\WINDOWS\system32\msxml6r.dll

Tags: windows-xp, mind-mapping

My uncle is trying to install the [MindJet MindManager Viewer 7](http://www.mindjet.com/support/tutorials/viewer) but get's the following error message :

> **MindJet MindManager Viewer 7 Installer Inform...**
>
> Error 1931. The Windows Installer service cannot update the system
>   file C:\WINDOWS\system32\msxml6r.dll because the file is protected by
>   Windows. You may need to update your operating system for this program
>   to work correctly.

His Windows XP SP3 system *is* up to date, by the way.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [Microsoft Support Article source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958897) about the issue of modifying MSXML* files:

> In Windows XP SP3 MSXML files were added to Windows File Protection

And according that support article: `There is no Hotfix at this time.`

I would suggest trying to install the application using [Compatibility Mode options for SP2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292533), but because it's an OS level protected file now this still may not work.

Otherwise you may need to wait for the MindJet team to release an update that's compatible with XP SP3.